# Automating the import of projects into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I wrote a batch file to do a SVN checkout that saves all the projects I checkout from a repository into my workspace and starts eclipse.

After starting eclipse, I need to import these projects but I wanted to find a way to automate this. Need help knowing how this can be done.

```
set svnbin="C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe"
set svnroot=  some_url 

%svnbin% list %svnroot%>projects.txt
type projects.txt
echo ============================================================%NL%  


set /p checkout="Enter project name to checkout="



set svnfolder= some_url/%checkout%/trunk/ 
set CheckOutLocation=C:\Users\user\workspace\



svn checkout %svnfolder%  %CheckOutLocation%\%checkout%\trunk\
```

Now , I have projects in my workspace folder . How can I automate eclipse
to add these existing projects by itself?

Comment: Please include some code that you've tried.

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the projects you are checking out are not eclipse projects already, then you can try running mvn command
`mvn eclipse:eclipse`
This will convert your project into eclipse projects and then you can import them into eclipse.

I have not tried this but this is my 2 cents -

If they are Eclipse projects when you check out, you can copy the .project, .classpath and .settings folder and into a folder and make this folder one of the projects of the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Hi Aravind, I am sorry if I wasn't clear but I am trying to automate the process of manually adding existing projects in the workspace through a batch script.   What my script does at the moment is to automate svn checkout of projects and adds them to my workspace. However in order to use these projects I need to add the existing projects from workspace . ( This is what I am trying to automate).